# protobuf in C++ with dynamic binding for google::protobuf::Message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Working with protobuf in C++, I have a series of messages that will share a single pair of encoding and decoding custom API, e.g., Pack() and Unpack();

But I soon realize that I must hardcode the message types to be able to decode the data into the correct data structure from stream.

Since inheritance is not supported, I then looked at the `Any` facility. However, the official doc is too concise to guide me with an working example.

I'd like to confirm whether or not the Any works like this:

Say if I have a few message types that I need to create from a factory on the decoder side, then ...

Step #1: I must define my proto3 like this

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Envelope {
   google.protobuf.Any actual_msg = 1;
   string id = 2;
}

message PublicProfile {
   string name = 1;
   int32 age = 2;
   bool isMale = 3;
}

message PrivateProfile {
   string nickname = 1;
   int32 money = 2;
}
```

Step 2: The encoder would work like this

```cpp
//encoder.cpp

Envelope payload;
payload.set_id("my.com/msg/profile.public");
PublicProfile pp;
pp.name = "Tom";
pp.age = 30;
pp.isMale = true;
payload.get_actual_msg().PackFrom(pp); // NOT Sure how to use PackFrom at all!


int pakSize = payload.ByteSize()
std::string packet(pakSize, '\0');
google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream aos((void*)packet.c_str(), pakSize);
google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream* cos = new google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream(&aos);
payload.SerializeToCodedStream(cos);
```

Step #3: Finally the decoder would need to

```cpp
// decoder.cpp

Envelope payload;
google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(packet.c_str(), packet.size());
google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream cis(&ais);
payload->ParseFromCodedStream(&cis);
google::protobuf::Any actual_msg = payload.actual_msg();
if (payload.id() == "my.com/msg/profile.public") {
    PublicProfile pp;
    actual_msg.UnpackTo(&pp);
}
```

Does it work this way?

Answer (score 2):

Since no one is up for an answer, I'm reporting my own findings.

We don't need an explicit ID in the protocol. `Any` has an ID built into it, generated by Protobuf automatically.

When decoding, simply call the designated method to retrieve the ID from the `Any` object and we are free to match it against any custom patterns

```py
myAnyMsg.type_url()
```

A typical URL looks like this

```
type.googleapis.com/<message_type_defined_in_proto>
```